# Python place the spider datas in an excel file

Tags: python, web-crawler, xlsxwriter

I lose 1 hour each day to classify information from websites so I'm trying to build a python spider that will get the data from a website and will classify them automatically in an excel file.

I already built the part to get the data but I do not know how I can append them in an excel file with the code I am using.

**here is the code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xlsxwriter

def spider_list(max_pages):
    page = 2
    while page < max_pages:
        url = 'http://yellow.local.ch/fr/q/Morges/Bar.html?page=' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class':'details-entry-title-link'}):
            href = link.get('href')
            spider_data(href)
        page += 1

def spider_data(item_url):
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
    for items in soup.findAll('h1'):
        print("\n" + items.string)
    for num in soup.findAll('a', {'class':'number'}):
        print(num.string)
    for mail in soup.findAll('a', {'class':'redirect'}):
        print(mail.string)


spider_list(3)
```

**Each group of information should be display horizontaly, here is an exemple:**

[image: excel table]

How should I do it ?
----------- EDIT -----------

Okay, now I created the last part of the code but it doesn't work why?

```
def spider_data(item_url):
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
datas = []
for items in soup.findAll('h1'):
    datas.append(items.string)
for num in soup.findAll('a', {'class':'number'}):
    datas.append(num.string)
for mail in soup.findAll('a', {'class':'redirect'}):
    datas.append(mail.string)
csv_create(datas)

def csv_create(data):
    myfile = open('mydatas.csv', 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(data)
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Is your csv empty? Show current and desired output. Also, on your edit, your indentation is off. As is, the append and csv function call is outside any defined function. Recall Python is a strong type language and hence syntax must be strictly adhered else errors or unintended outcomes will occur.

Comment: @Parfait Yes it's empty and there is this error message that says `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`

Comment: You are using binary output. Change `wb` to `w`. But note  `w` is to overwrite csv each time and `a` is to append to csv. You may need `a` to have csv grow with multiple rows. Adding `b` as second character is for binary data not strings.

Comment: @Parfait Thanks it was `a` it works now :) where can I find a documentation about the 'w', 'w+', 'a' and so on?

Comment: see this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel can read .csv files. If you have lines of text that look like this: "Title1, number1, website1 \n" you'll get an excel file that looks like that. You could either use python's built-in [csv methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) or build a pandas DataFrame and use [to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) (which would save you having to worry about writing commas and newline characters). Hopefully that helps

Comment: I'm going to try it, I'll let you know about this

Comment: Yeah, if you really need them to be .xls files, it looks like xlwt is the way to go. Or just open the csv in Excel and save as xls if it's just the one file

Comment: can you show me how I can put the title, the number and the website url in a csv file? I'm strugling to create a function that will let me do it...

Answer (score 0):

Using csv is certainly a simple way, but can be troublesome. ie when using quotes or getting data formated a way you didnt attended. Like 0:7 as a daytime by default.

I recommend you this sweet library which is more robust I think, hence it can set data-types and you can access cells by name, without numbering the commas.

[Python library for MS-excel creation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/)